# How do I find the asymptotes and parabolic branches of $C$ and $D$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space

> Let $f = -X^4 + X^3Y + Y$ and $g = -X^3 + X^2Y+Y$ and let $C = V(f)$ and $D = V(g)$. Find the points at infinity of the projective completion of $C$ and $D$, $\overline{C}$ and $\overline{D}$, and the asymptotes and parabolic branches of $C$ and $D$

For the first part, the projective completion of $C$ and $D$ are given by $V(F)$ and $V(G)$ where
$$F = -X_1^4 + X_1^3X_2 + X_0^3X_2$$
and 
$$G = -X_1^3 + X_1^2X_2 + X_0^2X_2$$
respectively. So making $X_0 = 0$ in both expressions, I have found the points $(0:0:1)$ with multiplicity $3$ in $\overline{C}$ and $2$ in $\overline{D}$, and $(0:1:1)$, with multiplicity $1$ for both curves.

The problem is that I don't know how to find the asymptotes and parabolic branches of $C$ and $D$. How do I find those? Thank you!

Comment: My guess: for $F$, the points at infinity are $P_1=(0:0:1)$ and $P_2=(0:1:1)$ as you say. Next I make a change of variables with $P_i$ as center, e.g., for $P_1$ you fix $X_2=1$ and write $F=-x_1^4+x_1^3+x_0^3$; here $x_i=X_i/X_0$. The lowest degree component of $F$ is $x_1^3+x_0^3=(x_1-x_0)(x_1-ax_0)(x_1-a^2x_0)$, where $a^3=1$ is a primitive root. The three lines $x_1-a^kx_0$ are asymptotes, since no one lies in the plane at infinity $x_0=0$. Next, for $P_2$... I hope this help :)

Comment: excuse me, $x_i=X_i/X_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) says, asymptotes are often considered only for real curves, and in this answer I will treat $C$ and $D$ as such. Your curves are of a particularly simple type, which makes finding the asymptotes easier.

$C$ is the graph of the rational function $Y=\frac{X^4}{X^3+1}=X-\frac{X}{X^3+1}=X-\frac{X}{(X+1)(X^2-X+1)}$ so $Y=X$ is an oblique asymptote, also $X+1=0$ is a vertical asymptote.

$D$ is the graph of the rational function $Y=\frac{X^3}{X^2+1}=X-\frac{X}{X^2+1}$ so $Y=X$ is an oblique asymptote.

Parabolic branches for graphs of rational functions are when the long division yields a higher degree polynomial than degree 1. Then the graph of the quotient polynomial, like $X$ above, is what the graph of the rational function tends to. If you want to find parabolic branches for more general algebraic curves, the link at wikipedia contains some information.